# Protractor clicking button twice

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I'm running a protractor test and for some reason my link is getting clicked twice. I'm assuming there is something basic I'm missing but can't figure it out. Thanks

```
describe('Quotegen', function() {
  test.browserMaximize();

  test.beforeAll(function() {
    test.login();
  });

   beforeEach(function() {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
  })

  describe('Clicking New Quote', function() {
    beforeEach(function(){
      // **** this click function is being run twice **** 
      element(by.linkText('New Quote')).click();
    });

    it('should take you to New Quote page', function() {
      expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toMatch('/site/');
    });
  });
});
```

New Quote HTML:

```
   <li class="nav-content"><a href="/site/" target = "_self">
     <i class="fa fa-bolt"></i>  New Quote</a>
   </li>
```

Comment: Could you show how the `New Quote` link is presented on a page? Thanks.

Comment: I'm no help, but I'm curious what the problem is

Comment: I have the same problem. But in my case it is not in beforeEach(), but in it(). Curious, first two specs use same function use it ok, but beginning from the third spec it starts to execute twice.